# How to check list for double elements and then delete both elements in Python 2

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I have a list of elements which I'd like to check for double elements (no element will be there 3 times, just once or twice) and then I'd like to remove the original and the copy of such an element. So in the end I need a list that contains all elements which have only been present once in the original list.

The elements of the list are lines so I need to check both, end and start point against each other to see, which lines are the same. I already wrote some lines of which none seemed to work. I have already written a small function that checks the lines and finds doublets but I can't seem to work out how to delete both the copy and the original element in my list. This is the function that finds double lines:

```
def cmp_lines(l1, l2):
   return(l1[0]==l2[0] and l1[1]==l2[1]) or (l1[0]==l2[1] and l1[1]==l2[0])
```

an example would be something like this:

```
list = [Line([1,0],[2,1]), Line([1,3],[4,5]), Line([2,1],[1,0])]

newList = [Line([1,3],[4,5])]
```

Using Python 2.x is a requirement.

Comment: provide an example of the input list and the corresponding expected output

Comment: list = [Line([1,0],[2,1]), Line([1,3],[4,5]), Line([2,1],[1,0])]

newList = [Line([1,3],[4,5])]

Hm I am really sorry but I don't know how to format code in the comments. But as you can see in the original list I have 2 lines(elements) which are the same (just in the different direction) and 1 line(element) which is unique. So in the newlist I just want the single line(element) and both doublets deleted

Comment: What is Line ? Is it a class that you've created ? or you've imported it from a library ?

Comment: Yes, actually it is called Segment in my programm but it is from a library we use at work.
To simplify I used the name line. But it can be regarded as a "classic" element in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write a function which takes as input the list of lines and filter it accordingly. That function will use cmp_lines to compare if two lines are equals.
Adapt the following method according to your objects and classes definitions.

```
def filter_lines(lst) : # lst is the list of lines to filter
    for i in range(len(lst)) :
        is_unique = True
        for j in range(i+1,len(lst)) :
            if cmp_lines(lst[i],lst[j]) :
               lst.pop(j) #remove the lst[j] from the list
               is_unique = False #a same line was found
               break;
        if not is_unique : #The line lst[i] is unique
           lst.pop(i) #remove lst[i] from the list
    return lst
```

Comment: Good evening and thank you very much for your answer. Sadly it does not solve my problem for as it still saves all lines, even though some are doubled. So it does still save the one instance of a line that was doubled before. Probably because if for exampe 1st[2] and 1st[5] are identical, it does not add [2] but then when it reaches [5] it only checks the list from [6] on and doesn't recognize, that [2] is the same. So I think I need to delete element [5] when I notice that it is the same as one coming before it but as I said, I can't seem to find a way to do that.But still thank you very much

Comment: Sorry.... It is now that I see your comment. I hope you've already found a solution to your problem. Anyway, I updated my answer to fit with your need.